# Java code efficiency, storing data versus method calls

Tags: java, performance, jvm

I have a question on code efficiency in java. I currently have a method that looks similar to the following

```
public class Response extends SuperResponse {

private Object ConfigureResponse = null;

public String getId() {
    if(this.getBody() == null || this.getBody().isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    } else {
        // Check if the ConfigureResponse has already been deserialized
        // if it has, there is no need to deserialize is again

        if(ConfigureResponse == null) {
            ConfigureResponse = JAXB.unmarshal(new StringReader(
                    this.getBody()), Object.class);
        }
        return ConfigureResponse.getConfigureResponse().getId();
    }
}
}// End class
```

In case of repeated calls to the `getId` method would it be better practice to save the Id string and return that directly, and save myself the method calls to return it? Or is the Java compiler intelligent enough to convert those method calls directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler is not able to do such optimization, but the JVM over time is able to strongly optimize such methods, but only if they are called frequently. This will obviously take time, therefore if:

- the methods called from the `getId` method are really time consuming and
- what is crucial here, you are sure  **they are the performance bottleneck of your application**, as *"premature optimization is the root of all evil"*

then it is better to introduce caching of the `getId` result, what can be accomplished by:

- adding a new attribute to the class `Response`:

  ```
  private String id;
  ```
- renaming the `getId` method to `populateId`
- creating a new `getId` method with such code:

  ```
  public String getId() {
      if (this.id != null) {
          return this.id;
      } 
      this.id = populateId();
      return this.id;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

`would it be better practice to save the Id string and return that directly`

In this case, no. calling a getter is a quick operation so you would not gain enough to justify a new variable which is a potential bug.

If you see some slowness later, it will still be time to add this variable if very necessary

`Premature optimization is evil`

Answer (score 0):

No, the compiler's not intelligent enough. To my experience, it is MUCH better to return the string directly and save yourself some time.